# Stop reloading Page after POST request via API in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby, axios

I do a post request via react axios to a api controller '/api/v1/reservations' from 'desks/index' , and I just wanna get a response of JSON without rendering a HTML. I know there are a lot of issues but nothing helped.

Problem:

```
Processing by DesksController#index as HTML
```

```
#routes

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy] do
        get :avatar, on: :member
      end
      resources :todo_items, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy]
      resources :desks, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy, :search, :freedesks]
      resources :reservations, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
    end
  end
```

```
# target controller

    class Api::V1::ReservationsController < ApplicationController

    def create
     if ....?
      date = params['reservation']['date'][0..9]
      desk = Desk.find_by(id: params['reservation']['desk_id'].to_i)
      reservation = Reservation.find_by(date: date, desk_id: desk.id)
      if reservation.nil?
        res = Reservation.create(date: date, desk_id: desk.id, user_id: current_user.id)

        render json: res, status: :created

      end
     else
      ...
     end
    end
```

I tried many things like:

```
render json: res, status: :created


respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :index }
end

render plain: "OK"
```

The only one is "working" is `render layout: false` but of course there is nothing then.
When I do get methods from my React component everything works fine.
I'm rendering via jbuilder.

```
json.array! @desks, partial: "api/v1/desks/desk", as: :desk
json.extract! desk, :id, :kind
```

I just wanna get only a json respond. This is not the problem but the HTML is rendering also. Why?

**UPDATE**
This is my post request:

```
    createReservation(id){
        setAxiosHeaders()
        axios
            .post('/api/v1/reservations', {
                reservation: {
                    date: this.state.resDate,
                    desk_id: id
                }
            })
            .then((response)=>{
                if(response.status == 201) {
                    notify("Reserviert!");
                    console.log(response)
                }
            })
            .catch((error)=>console.error(error));
    };
```

Response:

```
{data: {…}, status: 201, statusText: "Created", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
```

Comment: Probably your client sends wrong content type header in request

Comment: I updated my post request above @MikDiet

Comment: have someone an idea?

Comment: I think the issue might be that the user is clicking a link or submitting a form and you're not [preventing the default action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) or [stopping the event from propogating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Comment: Yes it's a button with click function to call the post request @max.

Comment: Then the issue most has very little to with the actual Ajax call and all the code here. Show us the event handler instead.

Comment: okay it works now. The page isn't reloading after post request.